# Request rate is large

Tags: node.js, azure, asynchronous, azure-cosmosdb

Im using Azure documentdb and accessing it through my node.js on express server, when I query in loop, low volume of few hundred there is no issue.
But when query in loop slightly large volume, say around thousand plus

I get partial results (inconsistent, every time I run result values are not same. May be because of asynchronous nature of Node.js)
after few results it crashes with this error

body: '{"code":"429","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Request rate is large\"]}\r\nActivityId: 1fecee65-0bb7-4991-a984-292c0d06693d, Request URI: /apps/cce94097-e5b2-42ab-9232-6abd12f53528/services/70926718-b021-45ee-ba2f-46c4669d952e/partitions/dd46d670-ab6f-4dca-bbbb-937647b03d97/replicas/130845018837894542p"}' }

Meaning DocumentDb fail to handle 1000+ request per second? 
All together giving me a bad impression on NoSQL techniques.. is it short coming of DocumentDB?

Comment: Can you check what's the pricing tier you have set for your collection? Is it `Standard S2` (1000 Request Units) or `Standard S3` (2500 Request Units)?

Comment: Gaurav, this is what is see in my DocumentDB properties blade, STATUS
Online
ACCOUNT TIER
Standard
LOCATION
Southeast Asia

Comment: Any way i could upgrade to S3 now?

Comment: You should be. Click on the collection in the portal and then click on Pricing Tier box. You should be able to change the pricing tier from S2 to S3. HTH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Gaurav suggests, you may be able to avoid the problem by bumping up the pricing tier, but even if you go to the highest tier, you should be able to handle 429 errors. When you get a 429 error, the response will include a 'x-ms-retry-after-ms' header. This will contain a number representing the number of milliseconds that you should wait before retrying the request that caused the error.

I wrote logic to handle this in my [documentdb-utils node.js package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils). You can either try to use documentdb-utils or you can duplicate it yourself. Here is a snipit example.

```
createDocument = function() {
   client.createDocument(colLink, document, function(err, response, header) {
        if (err != null) {
            if (err.code === 429) {
                var retryAfterHeader = header['x-ms-retry-after-ms'] || 1;
                var retryAfter = Number(retryAfterHeader);
                return setTimeout(toRetryIf429, retryAfter);
            } else {
                throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        } else {
            log('document saved successfully');
        }
    });
};
```

Note, in the above example `document` is within the scope of createDocument. This makes the retry logic a bit simpler, but if you don't like using widely scoped variables, then you can pass `document` in to createDocument and then pass it into a lambda function in the `setTimeout` call.

Comment: I just reread your question and have one more thought. The way DocumentDB handles scaling is via the number of Collections. So, if you need more than 2500 RUs/sec, you should partition your data and use a second Collection... even if you are no where near the storage capacity of one Collection. On the other hand, if your steady state is well below 2500 RUs/sec, but you have infrequent bursts of going over that, then the 429 handling approach above should be just fine.