# Request rate is large for remove request

Tags: node.js, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, mongoose-schema

When I try to find some docs in documentDB, all is good -

```
collection.find({query})
```

when I try to remove, all is bad

```
[mongooseModel | collection].remove({same-query})
```

I got

> Request rate is large

The number of documents to remove ~ 10 000 . I have tested queries in robomongo shell, which limits find results to 50 per page. Also my remove query fails with mongoose. I can't understand such behavior. How can I got in to `Request Limit` while remove query is a single request?

**Update**

Count with query also raise same error.

```
db.getCollection('taxonomies').count({query})
```

Comment: Have you looked at the RU cost of removal, compared to the RU allocation of the collection? If you're removing 10,000 documents, that will result in a large burst of RU consumption, since there's a delete operation executed for every one of the documents being removed. Not sure why you'd a throttle error for your `count()` operation. Are you still able to perform, say, an insert? Or does that give a throttle error as well?

Answer (score 2):

"*Request rate is large*" indicates that the application has exceeded the provisioned RU quota, and should retry the request after a small time interval.

Since you are using [DocumentDB Node.js API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sdk-node), you could check out @Larry Maccherone's answer in [Request rate is large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220404/request-rate-is-large/32226518#32226518) on how to avoid this issue by handling retry behavior and logic in your application's error handling routines.

---

### More on this:

[Dealing with RequestRateTooLarge errors in Azure DocumentDB and testing performance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bigdatasupport/2015/09/02/dealing-with-requestratetoolarge-errors-in-azure-documentdb-and-testing-performance/)

[Request Units in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units)

Answer (score 1):

This is an awful part of CosmosDB - I don't see how they intend to become a real player in the cloud database game with limitations like this.  That being said - I came up with a hack to delete all records from a collection through the MongoDB API when you are bumping up against the "Rate Exceeded" error.  See below:

```
var loop = true
while(loop){
    try {
        db.grid.deleteMany({"myField":"my-query"})
    }
    catch (err) {
        print(err)
        printjson(db.runCommand({getLastRequestStatistics:1}))
        continue
    }
    loop = false
}
```

Just update the `deleteMany` query and run this script directly in your mongo shell and it should loop through and delete the records.